# Mocha Test - can't pass test for rejected promise using async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, mocha.js, chai

Using mocha and chai, I'm trying to pass my second test to get the rejected promise, but instead I get this error `Error: the string "error" was thrown, throw an Error`.

```
function fn(arg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (arg) {
      resolve('success')
    } else {
      reject('error')
    }
  })
}

describe('Interpreting status', function() {
  it('should return the promise without error', async function(){
    const arg = true
    expect(await fn(arg)).to.equal('success')
  });

  it('should return the promise with an error', async function(){
    const arg = false
    expect(await fn(arg)).to.be.rejectedWith('error')
  });
});
```

Comment: If you await the promise you get an error, not a rejected promise.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me,

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));

function fn(arg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (arg) {
      resolve('success');
    } else {
      reject(new Error('error'));
    }
  });
}

describe('Interpreting status', function () {
  it('should return the promise without error', async function () {
    const arg = true;
    expect(await fn(arg)).to.equal('success');
  });

  it('should return the promise with an error', async function () {
    const arg = false;
    await expect(fn(arg)).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);
  });
});
```

The problem with your 2nd test is that when you do `await fn(arg)` you get an error being thrown instead of the rejected promise that you are expecting.
Hence, you see the message `Error: the string "error" was thrown, throw an Error :)`
Remember that if you `await` on a promise that rejects an error will be thrown that must be handled with a `try...catch`.
So, if you want to test with `rejectedWith` then don't use `async/await`.

Also, whenever you do a Promise rejection, you should reject with an error, not with a string.
I have changed the rejection value to `new Error('error')` and I am asserting for the error type in `rejectedWith`

**If you strictly want to go by your usecase, this should work for the 2nd test,**

```
  it('should return the promise with an error', async function () {
    const arg = false;
    try {
      await fn(arg);
      expect.fail();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).to.equal('error');
    }
  });
```